# Force chrome tab to active state

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Using chrome extension I'm trying to capture multiple tabs. I managed to achieve this using [chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-getMediaStreamId) and --whitelisted-extension-id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz since the extension will be used locally only.

Capturing works for active tabs but inactive tabs require to be selected for the capturing the start. I've tried using [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) by setting each tab active, this works, however it forces chrome to toggle between tabs until all are active.

Is there a more optimal way of doing this? Since this extension is for internal purposes, I can set flags and line switches.

Comment: "Active" is by definition the only tab, the currently focused one in the window, you can't have two.

Comment: Once a tab is considered active you can navigate away and it will continue to capture that tab even if it’s inactive. I’m wondering if there is a way trigger this behavior without having to bring tab to front.

Comment: No. This behavior is a specific requirement to prevent stealth malware.

Comment: I understand that, we’re already using flags to give our extension elevated permissions. Since this is for internal testing purposes we can modify and set flags and perform some actions public extensions cant. We wanted to consider all options before having to fork chromium and edit code.

Comment: Assuming the id is correct in your command line, there's probably no workaround.